# Syntax for finding a user in an Active Directory group

Tags: active-directory, active-directory-group

I'm trying to check an Active Directory group for a user. I'm using a test user that I know is there, while I'm trying to get the syntax right.

I'm searching our whole domain, and the filter I'm using is this:

```
(&(objectCategory=user)(CN=windowslogin)(memberof=CN=/#ITTest,OU=Security,OU=Groups,OU=FIRM,DC=our,DC=place,DC=com))
```

I think it's choking on the group part, because if I remove the whole `memberof` clause, and just search the entire AD, it finds the user. It only won't find them when I try and add in a clause to search a specific group.

Other things I've tried:

- List item with & without the escape character before the #
- With only the Groups OU and the DCs after the group name
- Adding OU's to the username part of the query
- Yelling at it

So far no luck.

I'm using a specialized tool to do the query but I'm hoping that the syntax it uses is close enough to the regular command line that someone might be able to point out my mistake.  I'm also a complete newbie to Active Directory, so there could be more than one thing wrong.

I realize this question is pretty vague, but if there is anyone who can offer any insight, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace.

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context - without further parameters, it defaults to the current
// domain you're logged in to, and to the whole AD tree
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    // find the group
    GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "YourGroupName") as GroupPrincipal;

    if(group != null)
    {
        // get the group members
        PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> members = group.GetMembers();

        // now you just need to find the user you're looking for
        UserPrincipal user = members.ToList().OfType<UserPrincipal>().FirstOrDefault(u => u.DistinguishedName == "CN=YourUserName");

        if (user != null)
        {
            // do something with user
        }
    }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Read more about it here:

- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but I don't *think* this helps me.  Like I said, I'm very new to AD.  It sounds like you're suggesting we add something to our system, but I'm not in a position to make a change like that.  I'm also not sure it would be compatible with the Integration tool we use.  At least I've never seen any templates or examples that look similar to what you've done here.

Comment: @VandaPaladino: no, no need to add anything - just **use it!**

Comment: Thanks again.  I'm using an integration tool, not writing something myself, so I don't think I can pull in a new namespace.  I think I'm stuck trying to make it work the complicated way.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that you're looking for the following filter:

```
(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=\#ITTest,OU=Security,OU=Groups,OU=FIRM,DC=our,DC=place,DC=com)
```

(replaced slash with backslash)

see [Search Filter Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475(v=vs.85).aspx)

This will show you all members of #ITTest group and all nested groups. However this method has some drawbacks, e. g. in enterprise environment it may lead to some performance issues

If you don't need nested groups search, you can still use memberOf: like in example you provided

Comment: Thanks that link is helpful.  The error turned out to be in a different part of the screen.  There's one box for the search DN and one box for the filter, at least one of my versions of the filter was right, but the DN box had CN=Users,DC=our,DC=place,DC=com and we had to take out the CN=Users.  Still not entirely sure why, but it's working now, at least with adding to groups.